# HttpRequestRetryHandler not getting called

Tags: java, android, httpclient, connection-timeout

I use `HttpClient` and `HttpRequestRetryHandler` to retry if connection or socket times out. So I turn my connection off and call API expecting `HttpRequestRetryHandler` to be called. But it does not get called. Not even entering the method.

**Code :**

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setIntParameter(
HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
            CONNECTION_TIMEOUT * 1000);
client.getParams().setIntParameter(HttpConnectionParams.SO_TIMEOUT,
            SOCKET_TIMEOUT * 1000);

// Retry handler which handles request retry
HttpRequestRetryHandler requestRetryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {

    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception,
                int executionCount, HttpContext context) {

        if ((exception instanceof ConnectTimeoutException || exception instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
                    && executionCount <= MAX_TRIES) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Retrying connection.");
            return true;

        } 

        return false;
    }
};

((AbstractHttpClient) client)
            .setHttpRequestRetryHandler(requestRetryHandler);
```

But at the same time I try to catch `ConnectTimeoutException` as shown below, and execution does enter the catch block for `ConnectTimeoutException`.

```
try {

    // Making API request

} catch (ConnectTimeoutException ce) {

    // Execution enters here
    ce.printStackTrace();
}
```

My avd runs on android version jelly bean.

Is there anything wrong in code?

**Logcat when printing ConnectTimeoutException trace :**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I'd like to share my solution (worked for me).

Many HTTP servers in general use are configured to drop persistent connections after a certain period of inactivity in order to conserve system resources, quite often without informing the client. See [HttpClient Connection keep alive strategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e659)

If the server drop the connection your HttpRequestRetryHandler will have no chance to try again (to do it's job).

So I solved in this way:

1. Implemented a Custom Connection Keep Alive Strategy

   ```
   mHttpClient.setKeepAliveStrategy(new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
       // Honor 'keep-alive' header
       HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
           response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
           String param = he.getName(); 
           String value = he.getValue();
           if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
               try { return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000; } 
               catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {  }
           }
       }

       ......

       //.Keep Alive for 30 secs
       return 30 * 1000;
     }
   });
   ```
2. Then I implemented the custom retry handler:

   ```
   HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {

       public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, 
                                   int executionCount, 
                                   HttpContext context) {
           // retry a max of 5 times
           if (executionCount >= 5) return false;

           if (exception instanceof NoHttpResponseException) {
               // Retry if the server dropped connection on us
               return true;
           }

           //.TODO your custom logic...

           Boolean b = (Boolean)
               context.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQ_SENT);
           boolean sent = (b != null && b.booleanValue());   
           if (!sent) {
               // Retry if the request has not been sent fully or
               // if it's OK to retry methods that have been sent
               return true;
           }

           // otherwise do not retry
           return false;
       }
   };

   mHttpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryHandler);
   ```

Comment: I tried your connection keep alive strategy, the request retry handler still doesnt seem to get called, what else can i do? how can i make sure that it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler.html)

I think the HttpRequestRetryHandler öacks of necessary implementations.

The [DefaultHttpRequestHandler](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.html) is another option.

Comment: I want to use custom handler so that I can decide to retry or not for any exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what solved the issue for me is initializing my custom handler with requestSentRetryEnabled = true. i.e. use :

```
static DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler myCustomHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(2, true) {
...
}
```

instead of:

```
static DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler myCustomHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler() {
...
}
```